# pdf("my_plot.pdf") produces a blank plot

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot and save it as a pdf file. I tried the following code:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2

pdf("my_plot.pdf")
plot(x,y)
```

This did create a pdf file named my_plot.pdf, but it was completely blank and size 0 kb. Any suggestions for how to get it to work?

If I do `dev.off` followed by `plot(x,y)` in the R Studio console, then the plot does appear correctly. But for some reason I can't get it to create a pdf plot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need `dev.off()` in your script. Apparently you messed up your devices. Use `graphics.off()` to close all devices, then do `pdf("my_plot.pdf"); plot(x,y); dev.off()`.

Comment: @jay.sf: Thank you, that worked! Should I always use `graphics.off()` before create a plot, and `dev.off()` after creating a pdf?

Comment: It's like so: `pdf()` starts the pdf device, then `plot()` the plot, then close the pdf device using `dev.off()` and the plot is saved. `graphics.off()` is not needed, but to keep in mind if you feel devices are messed up, which can easily happen if something yields an error in the `plot() etc.` code.